# Show total sales for each products on search results page Woocommerce

Tags: customization, woocommerce-offtopic, search

I customize my search results page like this when show the results as shown in the picture at the bottom

I want to show total sales for each products on search results page

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use third-party WooCommerce plugin 'Woo Total Sales' to display total sales of the specific product on product archive, product single or product search page.

Woo Total Sales: https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-total-sales/

You can also use below shortcode that plugin provides and add product ID to display its count.

```
[awts-total-sales product_id="0" include_setting="true/false"]
```

[image]